# Find the end of horizontal scrollable div and remove scroll event

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a horizontal scrollable div with different element inside. I have a js function for move inside the div with a `mouse wheel`; I need to remove the event when i arrive at the end of the div for continue scroll down.

This is my example fiddle code:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="element-1"></div>
    <div class="element-2"></div>
    <div class="element-3"></div>
    <div class="element-4"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="element-5"></div>
```

```
.wrapper {
  width:100vw;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.container {
   height: 100vh;
   width: max-content;
   overflow-x: scroll;
   overflow-y: hidden;
}

.element-1,
.element-2,
.element-3,
.element-4{
  width: 300px;
  height: 90vh;
  border: 1px solid green;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

.element-5{
   width: 300px;
   height: 100px;
   background-color: red;
}
```

```
$('.wrapper').on("wheel", function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        $(this).scrollLeft( $(this).scrollLeft() + evt.originalEvent.deltaY);
    });
```

Comment: Check the scroll position, and if it doesn't reaches the end, then scroll left, otherwise Pass

Comment: Hi Abin; could you suggest me the code to try? Thank you

Comment: Ok, let me give it a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is what you are looking for.

I just added a condition in your code to check if the container reached its right end.

```js
$('.wrapper').on("wheel", function(evt) {
  if($('.wrapper').width() + $('.wrapper').scrollLeft() < $('.container').width()) {
      evt.preventDefault();
      $(this).scrollLeft( $(this).scrollLeft() + evt.originalEvent.deltaY);
    }
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.container {
   height: 200px;
   width: max-content;
   overflow-x: scroll;
   overflow-y: hidden;
}

.element-1,
.element-2,
.element-3,
.element-4{
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

.element-5{
   width: 300px;
   height: 200px;
   background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="element-1"></div>
    <div class="element-2"></div>
    <div class="element-3"></div>
    <div class="element-4"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="element-5"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you Abin; it works! And have you got a solution if the user return to scroll Top, and restart scroll the horizontal div from the end to start?

Comment: The same in reverse way, you can give it a try.